# Portable ruby weapp on sinatra

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I have a webapp running on sinatra with several gems installed.

I would like to zip it and move to another machine, but since that machine doesnt have internet connection I would like to pack all the gems (sinatra, mongoid etc) with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two machines are similar and you’re using the same Ruby implementation (and version) you could use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/). Create a `Gemfile`, add the gems your app needs to it, then run

```
$ bundle install
```

to install those gems to the local machine.

You can then run

```
$ bundle package
```

which will copy all the gems used to the `vendor/cache` directory in your app. After zipping up and transferring the app to the other machine run

```
$ bundle install --local
```

to install all the gems from the `vendor/cache` directory on the other machine.

See the [docs for `bundle package`](http://bundler.io/v1.6/man/bundle-package.1.html).